# Define Settings programmatically

Tags: iphone, settings.bundle, root.plist

Is it possible to define the Root.plist in the Settings.bundle programmatically?

In the Settings – Mail, Contacts, Calendars, I can see all my accounts. I would like to do something similar, by having a number of user accounts being saved in the settings. From what I read so far, it looks like it isn’t possible, but I would like to be sure. Please note that I’m not looking to have a “Add Account” feature in the settings, just a listing of several accounts (number of accounts variable).

Comment: That would be an awesome Hack !!

Comment: Just for reference, still not programmable, but check out http://www.inappsettingskit.com/ - allows some other additions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible for anyone other than Apple. Third party developers have no way of programmatically changing the Settings bundle.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to find the answer in Apple's documentation, but I couldn't find it, so I was still in doubt.

Comment: And thank Apple, otherwise my Settings app would constantly crash with EXE_BAD_ACCESS.